# Working with bitcode

Tags: php, bitset

This is slightly OT for SO, because I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, instead just to understand how something might be implemented. But I am after code, so let's see how it goes...

Let's say we had a checkbox for each day of the week, and we decided to store any combination of those checkboxes as a single number, such that:

```
  0 = no days
  1 = Monday 
  2 = Tuesday
  4 = Wednesday
  8 = Thursday
 16 = Friday
 32 = Saturday
 64 = Sunday
127 = everyday
```

How might one go about implementing that logic in PHP so that if I submitted say, "13", PHP would know to tick only the Monday, Wednesday and Thursday checkboxes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bitwise `AND`s:

```
$input = 13;

if( $input & 1 ) {
  echo 'Monday';
}
if( $input & 2 ) {
  echo 'Tuesday';
}
if( $input & 4 ) {
  echo 'Wednesday';
}
// etc
```

### edit

You can avoid the `if`s with something like:

```
$input = 13;

$days = array('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');

for( $i=0; $i<7; $i++ ) {
    $daybit = pow(2,$i);
    if( $input & $daybit ) {
        echo $days[$i] . ' ';
    }
}

//output: mon wed thu
```

There's more than these two ways to skin this particular cat, but the 'best' way depends on what your result/output needs to be.

Comment: Oh wow - it's even simpler than I could have imagined! Now I feel really dumb :-(  - Thanks!

Comment: OK, can we do it without all the ifs?

Comment: @Strawberry added an example with only one `if`.

Comment: Wouldn't using a shift operator fit better than calling `pow()`?

Comment: @Wolf six of one, half dozen of the other. The only case in which it would make a difference is if PHP doesn't optimize integer powers of two operations to bitshift operations at either the interpreter level or in compiler optimizations. That said, any gains of `<<` vs `pow()` would be vastly overshadowed by much larger inefficiencies inherent to PHP itself. IF you get to the point where you have to worry about this level of micro-optimization you shouldn't be using PHP anyways. :P

Comment: My intention was *not* to optimize the performance, but comprehensibility. With shifting I associate an operation on bits in the first place as seems the binary AND to me. The `pow` function seems to be more maths-oriented. This I meant by using the word *fit*.

Comment: @Sammitch this is not working for me in smarty if syntax

Answer (score 6):

As to avoid code structure duplication (lots of similar `if` clauses) and introducing extra "magic" numbers (`2`, `7`), as shown [Sammitch's working suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22154865/2932052), I'd prefer the following.

```
$daymap = array(
    1 => Monday,
    2 => Tuesday,
    4 => Wednesday,
    8 => Thursday,
    16 => Friday,
    32 => Saturday,
    64 => Sunday
);

$input = 13;

foreach ($daymap as $code => $name) {
    if ($input & $code) {
        echo $name.' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `2` isn't a magic number, as it denotes the numeric system used (in this case `binary` - `0`'s and `1`'s). `7` could easily be switched out with `count($days)` to remove the magicness. That said, I agree that your method is better and easier to read.

Comment: @h2ooooooo sure, but we iterate the whole array, so their explicit usage isn't necessary. Looks the `"magic"` better?