# Separating days from MySQL field

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day, I have a problem wherein the value of days are formatted with MTWThF, ThF, TTh and so on. I am trying to convert into columns. this is my code:

```
SELECT 
dys,
CASE WHEN dys LIKE 'M%' THEN 'M' ELSE '' END AS M,
CASE WHEN (dys LIKE '%T%' AND NOT '%Th%') THEN 'T' ELSE '' END AS T,
CASE WHEN dys LIKE '%W%' THEN 'W' ELSE '' END AS W,
CASE WHEN dys LIKE '%Th%' AND NOT 'T' THEN 'Th' ELSE '' END AS th,
CASE WHEN dys LIKE '%F%' THEN 'F' ELSE '' END AS F,
CASE WHEN (dys LIKE '%S%' AND NOT 'Su') THEN 'S' ELSE '' END AS S,
CASE WHEN (dys LIKE '%Su%' AND NOT 'S') THEN 'Su' ELSE '' END AS Su
FROM sched
GROUP BY dys
```

and the results are

[Tb result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7ekJ.gif)

T is till detected on ThF same S from SSu. Do i missing something? Thank you

Comment: Break the problem down. Update the database (or create a view) with replace(replace(dys,"Th",X), "Su", "Y")) as schedEdit. Thursdays are now X, Sundays are now Y and all the days are a single value which can be identified with instr(schedEdit, "M") or "U", "X" etc.

Comment: Great! I will try that, thank you @Mike

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154793/working-with-bitcode