# how to find possible subsets of a given array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have an an table of week as

```
day_id  |   Day
----------------------
1       |  Monday
2       |  Tuesday
3       |  Wednesday
4       |  Thursday
5       |  Friday
6       |  Saturday
7       |  Sunday
```

Here i am using this table for multiple users as working days of employees, i want use subset of this array to store with each user profile. Is there any other solution then `implode(day_id)`

Comment: Don't implode these days into CSV, because that is hard to use in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is entirely unnecessary.

One idea is to imagine a bit wise representation of each weekday, whereby:

```
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 8
Etc
```

Every combination of days can then be represented by a single number from 1 to 127.

See [Working with bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154793/working-with-bitcode) for a fuller explanation

Comment: Thanks solution was helpful

Comment: how i can check this condition in smarty syntax, its not working for me in smarty

Comment: Only smarties have the answer

Answer (score 0):

using function days

if $is_number = true return number day else name day .

```
function days($is_number = true)
{
        $days       = array();
        $day_number = date("D", time());

        $day            = array(
                        'Mon' => 2 /* 'Monday' */,
                        'Tue' => 3 /* 'Tuesday' */,
                        'Wed' => 4 /* 'Wednesday' */,
                        'Thu' => 5 /* 'Thursday' */,
                        'Fri' => 6 /* 'Friday' */,
                        'Sat' => 0 /* 'Saturday' */,
                        'Sun' => 1 /* 'Sunday' */,
                    );

        $day_name   = array(
                        2 => 'Monday',
                        3 => 'Tuesday',
                        4 => 'Wednesday',
                        5 => 'Thursday',
                        6 => 'Friday',
                        0 => 'Saturday',
                        1 => 'Sunday',
                    );

        $number = isset($day[$day_number]) ? intval($day[$day_number]) : FALSE;

        if($is_number)
                return $number;

        return isset($day_name[$number]) ? $day_name[$number] : FALSE;
}
```