# why if condition not working in smarty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

Hi guys here i have a problem that i want to perform a check like

```
$input = 13;

if( $input & 1 ) {
  echo 'Monday';
}
if( $input & 2 ) {
  echo 'Tuesday';
}
if( $input & 4 ) {
  echo 'Wednesday';
}
// etc
```

Reference: [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154793/working-with-bitcode)
i want to perform this check in **smarty** [smarty link](http://www.smarty.net/)
please let me know the solution
i am trying like this

```
{if $input_bit & $day_bit}
//do anything
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables first using `assign`in smarty.

```
{assign var="input" value=10}
```

Then try with `if/else..` like below:

```
{if $input & 1}
//do anything
{elseif $input & 2}
//do anything
...so on..
{/if}
```

For more see [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl#idp42131888) and [if/elseif..](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if) in smarty.

Comment: value are already assigned, i can echo these values {$input_bit} and {$day_bit} smarty is not compiling this check syntax

Comment: if getting any problem  write php code inside `{php}..{/php}`.

Comment: i am trying this {php}if($aForms.days_bit & $aWorkingDay.bit_value){ selected } {/php} and actually i was trying {if $aForms.days_bit & $aWorkingDay.bit_value}checked{/if} in a checkbox input both are not working

Comment: which version of smarty is used?

Comment: thanks dear problem is solved, here the problem was that value were dynamic and was as string, i solved values in controller level an now it's working