# How to display the days on the view page if days id is multiple in the single column?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two-three tables. First is days and in the second table I am inserting the data

```
days_id days_name
    1   Monday
    2   Tuesday
    3   Wednesday
    4   Thursday
    5   Friday
    6   Saturday
    7   Sunday
```

In the second table

```
  id    | days_id  
  1     | 2,3,5
  2     | 1,3,7
  3     | 1 
  4     | 2
```

I know, it's the not correct way to insert multiple data in a column but still, I have to do this.
Now My issue is, I have to display the list in the table.

**Note**(This is not 100% my output. I just want to know how to display the days)

```
    id    | days_id  
    1     | Tuesday,Wednesday,Friday
    2     | Monday,Wednesday,Sunday
    3     | Monday 
    4     | Tuesday
```

What query I have to use it? I tried below query but it's displaying only first day.

```
SELECT *
FROM `b_list`
JOIN `days` ON `b_list`.`b_days` = `days`.`days_id`
WHERE `b_list`.`b_status` = 1
```

Tagging CodeIgniter because I am using it.
Would you help me out in this?

```
$result = $this->db->where(['b_list.batch_status'=>1])
            ->select('*, group_concat(days_name ORDER BY days_id ASC) as days_list')
            ->from('b_list')
            ->join('days','FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id,b_list.days_id)')
            ->get()
            ->result();
```

and using above code I am getting the below query

```
SELECT *, group_concat(days.days_name ORDER BY days_id ASC) as days_list FROM `b_list` JOIN `days` USING (FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id,b_list.days_id)) WHERE `b_list`.`batch_status` = 1
```

Comment: @Strawberry, My question is different. I am not asking for bad or not.

Comment: Here's an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154793/working-with-bitcode

Comment: @Strawberry, I checked that. That is not my solution. I am struggling for a query.

Comment: But you've already established that you know that the premise of the question is flawed. !?!

Comment: @Strawberry,Yes, right but still I have to find the solution to display the days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to join on a list and [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate them into a string:

```
SELECT b_list.id, group_concat(days_name ORDER BY days_id ASC) as days_list
FROM b_list
INNER JOIN days ON FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id, b_list.days_ids)
GROUP BY b_list.id;
```

[image: example output]

DEMO: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9fCJRNiSPwk8jQtFWuEFB/4

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: I tried SELECT *, group_concat(days_name ORDER BY days_id ASC) as days_list FROM `b_list` JOIN `days`  find_in_set(days.days_id,b_list.b_days)) but I am getting the error   "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(days.days_id,b_list.b_days))

Comment: The query in your comment is missing the `on` in the join. It also looks like you have an extranious bracket at the end. Maybe you should try it in a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com). You can fork my existing one.

Comment: actually, I am using CodeIgniter. and I am getting that output.

Comment: Regardless, it makes sense for you to put the query somewhere where we can help you. I can't help: "it doesn't work when I omit random parts of your working example". The fact that you're using CodeIgniter doesn't affect the mysql queries.

Comment: I updated my code. Can you please check it. what is the issue?

Comment: I think that one of the fields you're asking for in the `FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id,b_list.days_id)` doesn't actually exist. Check the names. In my example dbfiddle I stored the list of day IDs in `b_list.days_ids` (note the s suffix). I also think you can't select `*` in a query that uses a `group_concat()`. And finally, you have no `group by` so what should be distinct rows will just be one single long result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188458/discussion-between-user9437856-and-moob).

Comment: It works with joins in my example. I think codeigniter is getting in the way. Have you tried just using the complete query rather than using codeigniter's query builder. Eg: `$result = $this->db->query('FULL QUERY HERE');`

Comment: @Mood, That I haven't tried..give me time to try that also

Comment: You need to strip stuff out until you have the most basic working query. Then you can start adding things back in one by one to see what part is causing the error. Start with my demo query. Make sure the table and field names are correct (they might be different to those in my example). Just select the group_concat field only (nothing else). Exclude all WHERE clauses. If this works try adding stuff back in. Then when it breaks post a new question: ’why does adding xyz break this query?'

Comment: I tried this query I change the table name and field name.. SELECT batch_list.*,group_concat(days_name) as days_list
FROM `batch_list`
JOIN `days` ON   FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id,batch_list.batch_id)
WHERE `batch_list`.`batch_status` = 1
AND `activity_list`.`act_status` = 1 GROUP by batch_id               but I am not getting the proper output

Comment: I really recommend creating an example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) so you can replicate the problem in a way that we can help. I don't know what your tables or data looks like nor what output you're expecting. I have no more answers. I'll remove my answer shortly seen as though it hasn't helped you.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to use db-fiddle. I added my both table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCqm8SZpXEd97nGAEQ6aDd/1

Comment: Okay, so I've added the query for you: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCqm8SZpXEd97nGAEQ6aDd/2

Comment: Oh!! WOW, This time it's working perfectly, I was trying FIND_IN_SET(days.days_id, batch_list.batch_id) that's the reason it was not working.. Now it's working. Thanks, @Moob. Really I appreciate your patience and efforts and support.  Upvote from my side. Please update your answer. SO that I can refer in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is awful. Don't do it. But if you must:

```
DROP TABLE terrible_idea;

CREATE TABLE terrible_idea
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,days_id  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO terrible_idea VALUES
(1,'2,3,5'),
(2,'1,3,7'),
(3,'1'),
(4,'2');

CREATE TABLE hacky_solution
(i SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO hacky_solution VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(FIND_IN_SET(y.i,x.days_id),'%W')m FROM terrible_idea x,hacky_solution y;

SELECT id
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'
                     ,','
                     ,FIND_IN_SET(y.i,CONCAT(',',x.days_id))
                     ),',',-1)m 
                  FROM terrible_idea x,hacky_solution y
                  HAVING m <> '';
SELECT id
      , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday'
                      ,','
                      ,FIND_IN_SET(y.i,CONCAT(',',x.days_id))
                      ),',',-1)m
                   FROM terrible_idea x,hacky_solution y
                   HAVING m <> '';
+----+-----------+
| id | m         |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | Tuesday   |
|  3 | Tuesday   |
|  1 | Tuesday   |
|  4 | Tuesday   |
|  1 | Wednesday |
|  2 | Wednesday |
|  1 | Thursday  |
|  2 | Thursday  |
+----+-----------+
```